# Why it takes more time when calling excel functions in outlook VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing a macro in outlook for the first time and need some excel functions. So I go to Tools > Reference and choose the "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object  Library", then test it in the immediate window. Below is what I wrote in immediate window:

```
? WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now(), 2)
```

There is some observable but minimal lag (may be just 0.2s or less) for it to show the answer, but this is not the case if I try same thing in excel. I have to admit this does not hurt the macro much but I am curious. Why did outlook get the worksheetfunction object slower? Am I adding the library in a wrong way?

Update:
about preventing unqualified reference, is that I should use some code like below

```
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'main body here
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WorksheetFunction` object is a member of the Excel `Application` object. When you call a `WorksheetFunction` member from Outlook, you're implicitly creating an instance of Excel, which will take time to load.

If you need the WeekDay function, there's already something similar in the VBA library:

> Function Weekday(Date, [FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbSunday])
>
> Member of VBA.DateTime

Comment: And using unqualified references like that is likely to leave Excel tasks running in the background.

Comment: The WorksheetFunction object, and the Application object are both members of Globals, which means they automatically create themselves. If you don't assign the reference to a variable, you have no reliable way of destroying the Application when you're done.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is that what I need to avoid unqualified reference?

Comment: That should do, but if you're just trying to use the Weekday function, I don't understand why you need Excel at all. Just use the VBA.Weekday function? If you need other Excel functions, you could just recreate it in VBA, and avoid the overhead of loading Excel.